# Bind a List<string> to MvxListView in MvxActivity

Tags: mvvmcross

I want to bind a List to MvxListView which is defined as property in one of my ViewModel class/
How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the markup .axml u define the ItemsSource

```
<Mvx.MvxListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    local:MvxBind="ItemsSource MyStringList"/>
```

`MyStringList` is the List Property in your Viewmodel. INotifyPropertyChanged also needs to be implemented and the Activity itself must know it's viewmodel, there are lot of examples [here](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/wiki/MvvmCross-Tutorials)